# How to filter rows from CSV file and dispaly it on JTable using java

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable, rowfilter

I am reading data from csv file and displaying it on JTable.but I want to display only selected row for eg.where DesignSize=M

> DESIGNCOLOR,DESIGNSIZE,STARTDATE
>
> ORANGE,L,2013-06-12 00:00:00.0
>
> ORANGE,M,2013-06-12 00:00:00.0
>
> ORANGE,S,2013-06-12 00:00:00.0
>
> ORANGE,XL,2013-06-12 00:00:00.0
>
> ORANGE,XXL,2013-06-12 00:00:00.0

here is the code what I am doing

```
public class Csv2TableModel extends JPanel {

    public static DefaultTableModel createTableModel(
            Reader in, Vector<Object> headers) {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;
        Scanner s = null;
        Vector<Object> c;
        try {
            Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
            s = new Scanner(in);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                rows.add(new Vector<Object>(
                        Arrays.asList(s.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*", -1))));
            }
            if (headers == null) {
                headers = rows.remove(0);
                model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
            } else {
                model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
            }
            return model;
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {    
            String datafile = "C:\\seema\\CSV Files\\2013\\June\\12.csv";
            FileReader fin = new FileReader(datafile);
            DefaultTableModel m = createTableModel(fin, null);
            JFrame f = new JFrame();
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTable(m)));
            f.setSize(1000, 400);
            f.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to filter CSV file by specific criteria?

Comment: How about checking before you call `rows.add()` when you have the data in your `string`?

Comment: One way is to use a `TableRowSorter` which [sorts & **filters**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) a table.